# Android Streaming Internet Radio Service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, audio-streaming

I'm currently coding an android application to stream radio from an ip. I made a test app, where the streaming service is in the MainActivity, and it works.
However, I want to continue streaming the audio when the user goes to another application.

In my MainActivity I have a play/stop button, when clicked, the service will start or stop. My MainActivity handles the button change.

Start service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamRadio.class);
intent.putExtra("url", "http:/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/");
startService(intent);
```

Stop service:

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamRadio.class));
```

In StreamRadio.java I want a service that plays audio from the given     url. This is my current code, however, it is not working.

```
public class StreamRadio extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(intent.getExtras().getString("url"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

The Service gets called correctly, I receive an error

> E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1)

when testing on a physical device, and I receive these two errors on emulator:

> E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>      E/MediaPlayer: error (1,-2147483648)

Question: How can I make a service which streams the radio from an ip?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `IntentService`s stop themselves after the `onHandleIntent()` method completes. You want a regular `Service`.

Comment: True, I have read that, but the stream won't ever be completed, it's a continious stream. So in my opininion IntentService is good, but I have just started coding android apps.

Comment: I don't follow your logic there. Look at your stack trace for the cause of the crash.

Comment: I will take a look at     Service, thanks for your help. Any answers are still appreciated!

Comment: Changed code to Service, thanks @MikeM. , but I can't figure out how I can code this so it works.....

Comment: You want to `return START_STICKY;` in `onStartCommand()`. Beyond that, you need to be more specific than "it is not working". What doesn't work? Is the `Service` starting correctly? Is the `MediaPlayer` running at all? Is it crashing? Are you getting an Exception? If so, please post your stack trace.